# Finding if a multidimensional array is within an array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of arrays - similar to this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String[][] A = { { "a", "b", "c" }, { "d", "e", "f" }, { "g", "h", "-" } };
        String[][] B = { { "-", "e", "b" }, { "a", "h", "c" }, { "d", "g", "f" } };
        String[][] C = { { "a", "b", "c" }, { "d", "e", "f" }, { "g", "h", "-" } };
        String[][][] myArray = { A, B};

        for (String[][] s : myArray) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(s));
            if (Arrays.deepToString(s).equals(Arrays.deepToString(C))) {
                System.out.println("true");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to check if a value is in the array, however, this is the only method I have found to work and it is very inefficient.

Is there a better way to do this since most built-in methods do not appear to work?

I also tried to use a Set and that had the same issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy: never convert to strings. Try `deepEquals` it should do what you want, although you of course first have to dive into your `myArray` and iterate over the elements.

```
public static boolean contains(String[][][] set, String[][] obj) {
    for (String[][] elt : set) {
        if (Arrays.deepEquals(elt, obj)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This performs the contains function for your test set in about 4.5% of the time.

---

Java has type erasure when it comes to arrays over objects (including other arrays). As such it may be slightly faster to create `deepEquals(String[][], String[][])` yourself where you use `Arrays.equals(String[], String[])`, as you would not have to check if the objects are arrays of `String` at runtime, nor would you have to check if there are any arrays nested even deeper.

```
public static boolean fasterContains(String[][][] set, String[][] obj) {
    for (String[][] elt : set) {
        if (deepEquals(elt, obj)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean deepEquals(String[][] a, String[][] b) {
    int n = a.length;
    if (b.length != n) {
        return false;
      }
      
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!Arrays.equals(a[i], b[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This performs the contains function for your test set in about 3.5% of the time, while being only slightly more complex than the test above.

---

As a general hint: computers are not efficient when it comes to Strings (although newer Java versions did address this somewhat). Anyway, *never convert to string* for any comparison, calculation, concatenation or whatnot. Always compare bytes, integers or objects (i.e. the original data) unless there is really no other way.

---

If you just have a list of characters then there are two observations:

- `char[][]` should also work;
- or just a `String[]` of course, where the String consist of the various characters (which you can retrieve using `String#charAt(index)` and compare using `String#equals(other)`.

With the latter you can bring down the search time to about 2%.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to store/hash your arrays as StringBuilder and compare it with the StringBuilder formed in the multidimentional array.

StringBuilder is faster for String operations compared to String. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String[][] A = { { "a", "b", "c" }, { "d", "e", "f" }, { "g", "h", "-" } };
        String[][] B = { { "-", "e", "b" }, { "a", "h", "c" }, { "d", "g", "f" } };
        String[][] C = { { "a", "b", "c" }, { "d", "e", "f" }, { "g", "h", "-" } };
        String[][][] myArray = { A, B};
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
        for(String[] ss : C){
            for(String s : ss){
                for(char p : s.toCharArray()){
                            str1.append(p);
                        }
            }
        }
        String cc = str1.toString();
        for(String[][] s : myArray){
            for(String[] ss : s){
                for(String sss : ss){
                    for(char p : sss.toCharArray()){
                        str.append(p);
                    }
                    if(str.toString().equals(cc)){
                        System.out.println("true");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but it still only runs at 60% time. It's certainly a speedup, but nothing near the 20-50 *times* speedup that you can achieve by simply not converting to string. In the end, it is still a stringified solution with a lot of unnecessary complexity. Still, voted up since faster is faster.